# Get table 1 record that is common to mutiple table 2 records when there's a many to many relationship between tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, chats, users and chat_user, where chat can have mutiple users and users can have multiple chats. I want to get the chat that is common to all the given user ids.

**chats** (id)

**users** (id)

**chat_user** (id, chat_id, user_id)

I want to get chat that belongs to user 1 and 5 or multiple user ids

**Edit**

I'm using Laravel framework, so it's better if there's a way to get the result through one of parent tables(users, chats).

But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is not working with the query you wrote? Can you show it?

Comment: @Cid I wrote one but turns out it was a really stupid one which outputs a result that doesn't even close to the output I expected. So I don't think that's gonna help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to join the tables `chats` (the one that contains the informations you want) and the table `chat_user` (the one that contains the id of the chat and of the user) to apply where clause on the joined table.

In Laravel, I don't know.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM `chats` c
JOIN `chat_user` cu
    ON c.id = cu.chat_id
WHERE cu.chat_id NOT IN (
    SELECT cuu.chat_id
    FROM chat_user cuu
    WHERE cuu.user_id NOT IN (1, 5))
```

Comment: there are other chats also which are user 1 and 5 is part of, so IN caluse gives all the other chat ids also. For an example there is are chats between 1 and 5, 1 and 3, 3 and 5. so this gives those chats ids also. I want to get only the chat between 1 and 5. anyway thanks for the try :)

Comment: Ok I didn't understand it first, the chats between 1 and 5

Comment: there can be only one chat between 1 and 5, so chat between 1 and 5 :) that's what I'm trying to validate using this

Comment: @RavishaHesh this can do the job

Comment: Output of this one is also not what I expected, for some reason this outputs a chat with users 2 and 6 also. but this made me to seach for the solution from a different angle. So thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I also found that, have to replace id with chat_id on subquery select clause, this is great thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help @Cid

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the `userId` will be an input parameter here? Try the query below:

```
SELECT
*
from
chats
WHERE
id in (
SELECT
  chat_id
from
  chat_user
WHERE
  user_id = '1'
  OR user_id = '5'
group by
  chat_id
having
  count(*) = 2
)
```

The count(*)=2 will ensure only those chats where both user `1` and `5` are present.

Comment: Well, this one is little bit similar to one that I wrote, but 1st issue, there can be more than 2 users, 2nd like I commented on Cid's answer there can be mutiple chats where user 1 and 5 is part of

Comment: The WHERE clause will filter only those records which have user_id as 1 or 5 and the count(*)=2 condition is placed only on these records. This should ensure the chats where both 1 and 5 are present. In case of more users, the count(*) = x (where x is number of users) and the where condition should work.

Comment: the issue is when there are more than two users, I have to repeat the OR condtion to each user